# Is it possible to initialize Ruby from C++ more than once in the same process?

Tags: c++, ruby

I'm writing some unit tests. For that I try to initialize the Ruby interpreter and run code that uses it multiple times in a row. The first time it works fine, but on the second run, a crash in Ruby code occurs. It has been hard to nail the issue top-down so far, so I have tried to reproduce it bottom-up. Starting from this minimal example, taken right from the [Running Ruby in C](https://silverhammermba.github.io/emberb/embed/) documentation.

**Is it at all possible to initialize a Ruby interpreter multiple times in the same process? (Am I doing it wrong?)**

## Example Code

```
#include <ruby.h>
#include <iostream>

int rbCycle(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << "init" << std::endl;
    ruby_init();

    // char* options[] = { "-v", "-eputs 'Hello, world!'" };
    // void* node = ruby_options(2, options);

    // int state;
    // if (ruby_executable_node(node, &state))
    // {
    //     state = ruby_exec_node(node);
    // }
    // if ( state ) {
    //     std::cout << "error";
    // }

    std::cout << "cleanup" << std::endl;
    return ruby_cleanup(0);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    rbCycle(argc, argv);
    rbCycle(argc, argv);
}
```

My compilation command line:

```
clang++ -g -O0 -o rb -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/Headers -lruby ruby.cpp
```

## Observations

Running the `ruby_init()`, `ruby_cleanup(0)` cycle two times triggers a crash on the second cleanup call. However, with the commented code enabled, it already crashes on the `ruby_options` call on the second cycle.

Output and stack trace **with only init and cleanup**:

```
init
cleanup
init
cleanup

* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x120)
  * frame #0: 0x00007fffc549838c libsystem_pthread.dylib`pthread_mutex_lock
    frame #1: 0x00000001001b4c59 libruby.2.0.0.dylib`___lldb_unnamed_symbol2793$$libruby.2.0.0.dylib + 9
    frame #2: 0x00000001001b1722 libruby.2.0.0.dylib`___lldb_unnamed_symbol2766$$libruby.2.0.0.dylib + 31
    frame #3: 0x00000001000bf116 libruby.2.0.0.dylib`ruby_cleanup + 55
    frame #4: 0x0000000100000f3b rb`rbCycle(argc=1, argv=0x00007fff5fbffa30) at ruby.cpp:22
    frame #5: 0x00000001000010da rb`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007fff5fbffa30) at ruby.cpp:28
    frame #6: 0x00007fffc5281235 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

Output and stack trace **with the commented code enabled**:

```
init
Hello, world!
cleanup
init

* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x180)
  * frame #0: 0x00000001000befb4 libruby.2.0.0.dylib`ruby_options + 65
    frame #1: 0x0000000100000e3c rb`rbCycle(argc=1, argv=0x00007fff5fbffa30) at ruby.cpp:10
    frame #2: 0x000000010000107a rb`main(argc=1, argv=0x00007fff5fbffa30) at ruby.cpp:28
    frame #3: 0x00007fffc5281235 libdyld.dylib`start + 1
```

This is `ruby 2.0.0p648 (2015-12-16 revision 53162) [universal.x86_64-darwin16]` on macOS 10.12.5.

Comment: It might not be. What's the use case here? Could you `fork` each time you needed a Ruby process and terminate that child when you're done?

Comment: @tadman That would be technically possible, I'd consider it overkill for my case however. The other option would be to instantiate ruby once and reuse it from test to test. I was mostly looking into getting the tests more independent of general setup/teardown if possible.

Comment: You could create a singleton class that represents your Ruby interpreter which is initialized exactly once per run, though do keep in mind any Ruby modules, classes or constants you define will persist from one test to the next, so that may not be ideal. It's a tough call.